# Got error : "Unable to update project dependencies" while build solution

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my project solution, i have two project with setup project, now when i build solution i got project dependencies error. If i close visual studio and reopen then its solved but how to solve project dependencies error without closing visual studio?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing the problem firsthand, but Visual Studio has lots of little bugs like this. I find myself restarting Visual Studio a lot.